# How to get data responseJSON when ajax request returns 4xx?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have this Ajax request

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Default.aspx/CreateNewCase',
        data: JSON.stringify(
            {id: ID }
        ),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, status) {
            //when server returns 200
            loadCase(ID, data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //when server returns 4xx. For example 409
            if(data.status == "409")
            {
                var newData = data.responseJSON;
                //error newData is undefined
                loadCase(ID, newData);
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

My WebMethod will always return an object whether the result is 200 or 4xx. On ajax.success, it returns a JSON object data. However on ajax.error, I cannot get the data.responseJSON.

I have read somewhere that JQuery prevents data to be read after an error. I have tried with .fail and .complete too, but I still cannot get the value when Ajax request returns 4xx.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: In your `error:` function, just `console.log(data)` to see what it is that you're actually getting back. Then you can make a decision from there.

Comment: Have you tried `responseText` ? It will depend on what exactly the web server returns. Some return errors as JSON as well, some return a HTML error page, some return an empty page, some return custom errors. Et cetera. Have a look at the data type returned for the AJAX call and edit the appropriate error handler on the web server.

Comment: @TJBlackman Well I wanted a JSON object. But data.responseJSON is not available on data.

Comment: @Shilly I tried that too. It just returns 'Illegal Request' when 400. 'The page can not be displayed due to a conflict' when 409.

Comment: yeah that's the issue. The request can't be served since there's a conflict in the request, so you'll never get any sensible JSON data out of it unless you want to wrap this error in JSON. The point is, all AJAX calls can and will fail at some point, so code the rest of your app so it can handle it. Maybe you want to log the error, or notify the user the request is not possible etc. But you won't be able to `loadCase` on an error, since your data is not available. The 'Illegal Request' and 'The page can not be displayed due to a conflict' text are the default handlers of your web server.

Comment: @Shilly so you are telling me that there is absolutely no way to get the object returned by the WebMethod (data) when ajax returns 4xx? Of course I could try a different approach / logic on my WebMethod by not using statusCode 4xx at all. But I am just asking because I am still learning about Ajax and well, maybe there is a way to get the data that I haven't discovered yet.

Comment: statusCode 4xx means there's an error with serving the request. It's usually the web server that determines the response and the statuscode of that response when it throws an error. You can overwrite the default error pages with anything you want inside the webserver itsself, but not inside a clientside app. So you always have to be prepared to handle things like a 404 page not found, a  500, server not found and such.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks for your information. By the way I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the answer. I have to add this parameter inside `<system.webServer>` on the web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough" >
      <clear/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

Then you can access your data like this:

```
error: function (data, status) {
       if (data.status == "409") {
             var myData = data.responseJSON;

             //do stuff here
       }
}
```